# Better cap needed for toilet bolts

Tags: plumbing, toilet

See the white cap in this image
[image]

I don't know what it is called but I wish it wouldn't keep coming off the bolt/nut on my toilet. Is there a way to fix this? Get a better one? I don't know what to google for. Can you help?

Comment: common sense would tell you to google `toilet mounting bolt cap` .... the oval piece under the nut may be upside down or there is a missing component

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix might be using white poster putty / sticky tack.  If that doesn't hold, try a dab of superglue.  Each of these are available at the dollar store.  For a slightly more expensive option, perhaps some white adhesive silicone caulking.  All of these options should hold the cap in place enough to not blow off in the wind, but stilll allow you to break open the cap again if you need to ever remove or tighten the bolts.

Answer (score 1):

Decades ago the caps used to be made that fit tightly and never came off. The problem was, they were difficult to clean and people left cleaning solution around them, which would eventually seep inside and corrode the bolts to where they would break off. So the industry changed to leave the caps loose fitting so that when cleaning, it comes off and you can clean underneath and also make sure to get rid of any leftover cleaning solutions and let them dry before replacing the cap.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is install new bolts under the toilet attached to your toilet flange that way it doesn’t wobble back and forth. Once you get a wax ring and have the toilet over the hole and situated where you want it, press the toilet down to the floor to seal the wax ring to the toilet. The new bolts will be more then long enough to install the china cap base, then a washer and finally the nut. After that you will almost always find that the bolt is too long, so once you tighten the nut down to your desired tightness. Use a saw with a metal cutting blade and cut the bolt just above the nut. Or you can use a grinder. Your choice. Once you have cut the excess bolt off, put the cap on top of the base you originally put down and apply pressure until you hear a snap. After that you are good to go. I hope this helps

Comment: Needs new bolts with the plastic snap washers for those caps, +1. Which probably means pulling the toilet. Careful with a grinder; sparks are hot enough to mar porcelain.